# Int being changed into tuple during while loop

Tags: python, loops, tuples

I'm new to python and I thought it would be a good way to learn by creating a sleep button for windows 11 since it doesn't seem to have one. At any rate, I got the sleep function down and can make my puter sleep but I wanted to add a sleep timer as well. When I try to do a while loop to count down an int, it will work the first time and count down to 9, but the second time through the loop I get the error.
"TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'int'"

I don't really understand why. I've even tried to explicit the variable and it still ends up tupling it.
If I try to use the logical operations -= I also get the error

"TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'int' and 'tuple'"

I'm sure its something painfully obvious, so thanks for any help.

```
import os
from tkinter import *
import time
Sleep_Timer = 10
app = Tk()
app.geometry()
app.title("Purple Monkeys Sleep Button")
app.config(background="black")
icon = PhotoImage(file='logo.png')
icon2 = PhotoImage(file='logo2.png')
app.iconphoto(True, icon)
def sleep():
    os.system("rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState 0,1,0")
#def SetSleep_Time():
def GetSleep_Time():
    global Sleep_Timer
    while Sleep_Timer > 0:
        Sleep_Timer = int(Sleep_Timer - 1),
        print(Sleep_Timer),
        time.sleep(1),
        print("notsleeping")
        GetSleep_Time,
button = Button(app,
                text='SLEEP',
                command=GetSleep_Time,
                font=("Comic Sans",42),
                fg="green",
                bg="black",
                image=icon2,
                compound='bottom',
                activeforeground="green",
                activebackground="black")
button.pack()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: The comma creates a tuple. Why do you have a comma at the end of each variable assignment?

Comment: `Sleep_Timer = int(Sleep_Timer - 1),` why are there trailing `,` all over the place??

Comment: Yeah, thanks again. I"m coming from C++ so thought I had to have a , or ; pretty well at the end of them all. I cleaned them all up now and it works great.

Comment: fyi, semicolon `;` is permitted to end the line (and can be used to have multiple things in one line), although not seen as good style (because either you have multiple things in one line - which is ugly, or the semicolon does nothing) - but might ease the transitioning into python. :)